# Is using java reflection in aws lambda a bad practice?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, reflection, aws-lambda

First of all, I know it's plenty of already asked (and generically answered) questions around here about how good of a practice it is to use Java Reflection, but I'm specifically wondering how bad it is in a specific context that is AWS Lambda.

I'm thrilled and amazed on the power of Java Reflection and I wrote some utility methods to more easily and (code length) efficiently execute some tasks in my serverless architecture, in particular when I have to deal with Dynamo DB queries.

I think that AWS Dynamo DB sdk lacks of some powerful facilities and that the `DynamoDBMapper` class is far from the perfection, but it still might be because of some lack of knowledge by myself.

Going straight to the point, and thinking on a sentence I've heard yesterday about lambda, "you don't pay for the code storage", I'd like to know, from your experience, if I'd rather write tons of boilerplate code or using reflection is good enough.

Here's an explanatory enough example, that I use to get the real attributeName of a field or a method from a class mapping a DynamoDBTable:

```
private static <T extends Bean, A extends Annotation> String getBeanKeyAttributeName(Class<T> tClass,
        Class<A> annClass) {
    Field field = Arrays.stream(tClass.getDeclaredFields()).filter(f -> f.isAnnotationPresent(annClass)).findAny()
            .orElse(null);
    if (field != null) {
        String s = getAttributeName(annClass, field.getAnnotation(annClass));
        if (s != null)
            return s;
        return field.getName();
    }
    Method method = Arrays.stream(tClass.getDeclaredMethods()).filter(f -> f.isAnnotationPresent(annClass))
            .findAny().orElse(null);
    if (method == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    String key = method.getName();
    if (key.startsWith("get")) {
        key = key.replaceFirst("get", "");
        key = (key.charAt(0) + "").toLowerCase() + key.substring(1);
    }
    String s = getAttributeName(annClass, method.getAnnotation(annClass));
    if (s != null)
        return s;
    return key;
}

private static <A extends Annotation> String getAttributeName(Class<A> annClass, A annotation) {
    try {
        Method attributeNameMethod = annClass.getMethod("attributeName");
        attributeNameMethod.setAccessible(true);
        String s = (String) attributeNameMethod.invoke(annotation);
        if (!s.isEmpty())
            return s;
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
            | InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

EDIT: I might have not been very precise in describing my question. There is not an actual problem, I'm wondering if the usage of the reflection might uselessly slow down my lambda invocation and if anybody has every made some tests and report some results.

Comment: There's no difference between using reflection in Lambda and anywhere else, and different people come down on different sides of the question. Perhaps you should describe the _actual_ problem that you're having, and why the Dynamo mapper doesn't solve that problem?

Comment: I might have not been very precise in describing my question. There is not an actual problem, I'm wondering if the usage of the reflection might uselessly slow down my lambda invocation and if anybody has every made some tests. Adding this to the question, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: This *might* be suitable for software engineering stack exchange - you might get better answers there.

Comment: @Airhead when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat Noted, makes sense.

Comment: Looking up for the fields every call is a slower than invoking a method, if you can store the reference of the reflected field you will almost not note the difference. Also, if the fields are public, try using Unreflection as the stored reference